# Sum the odds numbers of a "number"

Tags: r

I am trying to sum the odds numbers of a specific number (but excluding itself), for example: N = 5 then 1+3 = 4

```
a<-5
sum<-function(x){
  k<-0
  for (n in x) {
    if(n %% 2 == 1)
      k<-k+1      
  }
         return(k)
}

sum(a)

# [1] 1
```

But the function is not working, because it counts the odds numbers instead of summing them.

Comment: `sum(seq(1, N - 1, 2))`, no? Also: don't overwrite base R's sum function, that will likely make you sad in future.

Comment: @dash2 make this an answer and you get my vote. You benchmark not badly against the currently accepted solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may use vectorized approach

```
a1 <- head(seq_len(a), -1)
sum(a1[a1%%2 == 1])
[1] 4
```

---

If we want a loop, perhaps

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  s <- 0
  k <- 1
  while(k < x) {
    if(k %% 2 == 1) {
      s <- s + k
    }
     k <- k + 1
     
     }
s

}
f1(5)
```

---

The issue in OP's code is

```
for(n in x)
```

where `x` is just a single value and thus `n` will be looped once - i.e. if our input is 5, then it will be only looped once and 'n' will be 5.  Instead, it would be `seq_len(x -1)`.  The correct loop would be something like

```
f2<-function(x){
  k<- 0
  for (n in seq_len(x-1)) {
    if(n %% 2 == 1) {
     k <- k + n 
    }
    
  }
    k    
}


f2(5)
```

NOTE: `sum` is a `base R` function.  So, it is better to name the custom function with a different name

Comment: Thanks for the answer and one question more, in the case that the argument is a numeric vector for example. c(3,4,5), the function works in the same way?

Comment: @DrJS Then you don't need the `seq_len`.  i.e. `a1 <- c(3, 4, 5)` and inside the function you remove the last element `for(n in x[-length(x)])`

Comment: @DrJS should the result be `3`? because in a1, the last element i.e. 5 is not used, and thus you get 3 as output as `4` is not used as well

Comment: @DrJS If you meant to do the same calculation on each element, then `Vectorize(f2)(a1)` (from the 'f2' in the solution i posted).  You can check individually i.e. `f2(a1[1])`, `f2(a1[2])`, `f2(a1[3])`

Comment: I tried it: `a1 <- c(3, 4, 5) f2<-function(x){ k<- 0 for(n in x[-length(x)]){ if(n %% 2 == 1){ k <- k + n }  } return(k) }`  `f2(a1)`, output is [1] 3, and it should give for 3 output 1, for 4 output 4 and for 5 output 4 , because 3 has 1 and 3, 4 has 1 and 3 and 5 has 1, 3, 5

Comment: @DrJS what i meant is `Vectorize(f2)(a1)#
[1] 1 4 4`. (using the `f2` from my post).  Sorry, initially I got confused by your comment thinking that you want the logic to be different

Comment: Perfect, I understood, thank for your helping.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematically, we can try the following code to calculate the sum (`N` could be odd or even)

```
(ceiling((N - 1) / 2))^2
```

Comment: @tjebo I updated my solution for general cases, so it should work for both even or odd `N`.

Comment: @tjebo I guess it may have almost the same performance with the one without `ceiling`

Answer (score 3):

It's simple and it does what it says:

```r
sum(seq(1, length.out = floor(N/2), by = 2))
```

The multiplication solution is probably gonna be quicker, though.

NB - an earlier version of this answer was

```r
sum(seq(1, N - 1, 2))
```

which as @tjebo points out, silently gives the wrong answer for `N = 1`.

Comment: nice +1 the only drawback that I found (when comparing those solutions) is that this here fails with N = 1. But I guess this is not really a matter.

Comment: No, it totally matters! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We could use logical statement to access the values:

```
a <- 5
a1 <- head(seq_len(a), -1)

sum(a1[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

output:

```
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Fun benchmarking. Does it surprise that Thomas' simple formula is by far the fastest solution...?

```r
count_odds_thomas <- function(x){
  (ceiling((x - 1) / 2))^2
}

count_odds_akrun <- function(x){
  a1 <- head(seq_len(x), -1)
  sum(a1[a1%%2 == 1])
}

count_odds_dash2 <- function(x){
  sum(seq(1, x - 1, 2))
}

m <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  akrun = count_odds_akrun(10^6),
  dash2 = count_odds_dash2(10^6),
  thomas = count_odds_thomas(10^6)
)
m
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>    expr      min         lq        mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   akrun 22117564 26299922.0 30052362.16 28653712 31891621 70721894   100
#>   dash2  4016254  4384944.0  7159095.88  4767401  8202516 52423322   100
#>  thomas      439      935.5    27599.34     6223     8482  2205286   100

ggplot2::autoplot(m)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

Moreover, Thomas solution works on *really big* numbers (also no surprise)... on my machine, count_odds_akrun stuffs the memory at a “mere” 10^10, but Thomas works fine till Infinity…

```
count_odds_thomas(10^10)
#> [1] 2.5e+19

count_odds_akrun(10^10)
#> Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```